# Regular Expression C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need use c# RegEx to process a string. The idea is delete initials characteres, like a substring.

Example string := "04|aH 800 A574a C.R.";

The result should be "H 800 A574a C.R.".

But the patron is variable, because the string can be "4|aProtestas populares" and the result should be "Protestas populares"

Summarizing, I need the substring after a "|x" ignoring what is before this expression.

Thanks...

PD: Sorry by my english :S

Answer (score 4):

```
var stringNew = Regex.Replace(stringOld, @"^.*?\|.", "");
```

This removes everything

- at the start of the string `^`
- containing anything `.*?`
- ending in a pipe `|`
- plus any one character that follows `.`

Comment: You should probably make the `.*` lazy, in case there are additional pipes somewhere later.

Comment: Another improvement would be to use `[^|]*` instead of `.*?`. This explicitly matches non-`|` characters, so it's guaranteed to stop at the first `|` without any need to backtrack, so you don't need a lazy quantifier.

Comment: That's right.. I have a problem with strings that have more than one "|"... For example:
string text = "0|tAndrómeda|g(14) :20-22 (Octubre-diciembre 1984)";
The result should by 
Andrómeda (14) :20-22 (Octubre-diciembre 1984)
But the actual result is: (14) :20-22 (Octubre-diciembre 1984)

Comment: @user207123: So, the "|g" inside the text should be replaced by a space?

Answer (score 2):

If the string always has the pipe and one char after it, then what you want to keep, you can just use `String.IndexOf()` . Using one string method would be much faster then using a RegEx Object.

```
string str = "04|aH 800 A574a C.R.";
int nIndex = str.IndexOf('|') + 2;
string substr = str.Substring(nIndex); // contains "H 800 A574a C.R."
```

Answer (score 0):

This Regex gives you desired result :

```
(\|)[a-zA-Z](?<wanted>[\s\S]+)$
```

Group named 'wanted' gives the after "|x".